# Web Audio API and Audio Download and Protection

Tags: javascript, audio, web-audio-api

I'm reading a book about Web Audio API.
In the book it states that to play and load a sound using the WEB AUDIO API, there are 4 steps that needs to be taken:

1.) Load the sound file with XHR and decode it. (Will end up with a 'buffer')
2.) Connect the buffer to audio effects nodes.
3.) To hear the sound, connect the last node in the effects chain to the destination.
4.) Start the sound.

My question is...given these 4 steps, is there a way for the user of the website that uses the Web Audio to download the audio/audios played on the website???

If so, how does one prevent this.

or does it being 'buffered' prevent it from being illegally downloaded?

I would like to find a way to protect the audio files I use inside my game/app that I put up on the webpage that are played with the Web Audio API.....

Thank you....

Comment: I am not familiar with web-audio but as a general rule... if the user can see (or hear it) you cannot prevent them from saving it.

Answer (score 2):

EASILY save it, no.  But 1) if it's being transferred as an MP3, etc file the user can go into their network cache and copy it; there's no inherent DRM or anything.  2) Even if the sound was being generated completely from scratch (e.g. mathematically) the user could use a virtual audio device like [Soundflower](https://rogueamoeba.com/freebies/soundflower/) to save the output.

So no, it's not really possible to prevent the user from saving audio files.

Comment: Hi, will loading the sound with XHR and decoding it (step 1 above) end up as a MP3 if the original file is a MP3??   How does one go to the network cache and copy it?  I would like to try that process and see how convenient or inconvenient it is....Thank you...

Comment: @preston : Here is a page that uses web audio and loads mp3 files: http://www.justgoscha.com/binaural-webaudio/ . Use Chrome to open the site, then press F12 or CMD/CTRL+ALT+i. This opens DevTools. Go to **Network** tab. Now reload the page. You can see everything that is downloaded in the Network tab. You can download/open the mp3 file by double clicking on them.

Comment: @JustGoscha ...That's a cool website... It was very convenient to get the audios based on your instructions.....That's too bad...I guess I have no way of keeping the audio files private......Thanks for sharing...